# TYPESCRIPT: Two identical interfaces are used. But only one of them works

Tags: typescript

I am writing this IDocumentFilingDto.ts file.

```
import { DocumentOrigin } from "./IDocumentFilingDto";


// export const enum DocumentOrigin {
//     Original,
//     Kopie,
//     OverenaKopie,
//     DS,
//     DSSKonverzi,
//     Elektronicky,
// }

export interface IDocumentFilingDtoGen {
    UniqueId?: any;
    Title?: string;
    DocumentId?: string;
    Binder?: any;
    CommunicationType?: any;
    Origin?: DocumentOrigin;
    CompanyId?: any;
    DocumentCategoryId?: any;
    DocumentTypeId?: any;
    CompanyOriginal?: string;
    SiteUrl?: string;
    hasSubmitted?: boolean;
    isModified?: boolean;
    IsLocalOnly?: boolean;
}
```

And it works, I do not get any type error.

Now I will comment out the local DocumentOrigin interface. At the same time, I will comment in the imported DocumentOrigin.

```
//import { DocumentOrigin } from "./IDocumentFilingDto";

export const enum DocumentOrigin {
    Original,
    Kopie,
    OverenaKopie,
    DS,
    DSSKonverzi,
    Elektronicky,
}

export interface IDocumentFilingDtoGen {
    UniqueId?: any;
    Title?: string;
    DocumentId?: string;
    Binder?: any;
    CommunicationType?: any;
    Origin?: DocumentOrigin;
    CompanyId?: any;
    DocumentCategoryId?: any;
    DocumentTypeId?: any;
    CompanyOriginal?: string;
    SiteUrl?: string;
    hasSubmitted?: boolean;
    isModified?: boolean;
    IsLocalOnly?: boolean;
}
```

When I do that, I no longer use the imported DocumentOrigin interface and I start to use the local DocumentOrigin interface. That is the only change.

The imported DocumentOrigin interface is the same as the local DocuemntOrigin interface. They are identical. But the surprising thing is that once I start to use the local DocumentOrigin interface, I get this error.

> [07:20:52] Error - typescript -
> src\webparts\documentUploadWebPart\components\DocumentHeader\DocumentHeader.tsx(462,60):
> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ UniqueId?: any; Title?: string;
> DocumentId?: string; Binder?: any; CommunicationType?: any; Ori...' is
> not assignable to parameter of type 'IDocumentFilingDtoGen'.
> [07:20:52] Error - typescript -
> src\webparts\documentUploadWebPart\components\Dtos\DocumentFilingDtoGen.ts(28,12):
> error TS90010: Type 'DocumentOrigin' is not assignable to type
> 'DocumentOrigin'. Two different types with this name exist, but they
> are unrelated.

Why is this happening? It does not make sense. The two interfaces are identical and yet, one of them works and the other does not. Why is that?

Appendix:

Somebody in comments asked me to provide also the IDocumentFilingDto.ts file. Here it is.

```
export const enum DocumentOrigin {
    Original,
    Kopie,
    OverenaKopie,
    DS,
    DSSKonverzi,
    Elektronicky,
}

export interface IDocumentFilingDto {
    UniqueId: any;
    Title: string;
    DocumentId: string;
    Binder?: any;
    CommunicationType: any;
    Origin?: DocumentOrigin;
    CompanyId: any;
    DocumentCategoryId: any;
    DocumentTypeId:any;
    CompanyOriginal?: string;
    SiteUrl?: string;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide IDocumentFilingDto data as well ?

Comment: Certainly. I hope it will easy to read here in comments.

export const enum DocumentOrigin {
    Original,
    Kopie,
    OverenaKopie,
    DS,
    DSSKonverzi,
    Elektronicky,
}

export interface IDocumentFilingDto {
    UniqueId: any;
    Title: string;
    DocumentId: string;
    Binder?: any;
    CommunicationType: any;
    Origin?: DocumentOrigin;
    CompanyId: any;
    DocumentCategoryId: any;
    DocumentTypeId:any;
    CompanyOriginal?: string;
    SiteUrl?: string;
}

Comment: No, it is terrible to read:) I wil try to find some other solution.

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar I have edited my question. I did not know this was possible. The IDocumentFilingDto file is part of the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript enums are special in several ways. One of those ways is that enum members have only a one-way equivalence with their actual values. For example, an enum member with the value "foo" can be used in a place where a string could be used, but a variable (or another enum's member) with the value "foo" couldn't be used in a place where a member of the first enum is required.

Where an enum member is required to be used, that specific enum's members must be used, it's not enough to use the same value or even an identical member from another enum.

For example:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  EXAMPLE = 'example',
}

enum MyOtherEnum {
  EXAMPLE = 'example',
}

function useMyEnum(arg: MyEnum): void {}

useMyEnum(MyEnum.EXAMPLE); // Totally fine

useMyEnum('example'); // Not allowed, even though it's the same value
useMyEnum(MyOtherEnum.EXAMPLE); // Not allowed, even though it's the same value and an enum member

function useValue(arg: 'example'): void {}

useValue(MyEnum.EXAMPLE); // Totally fine
useValue('example'); // Also fine
useValue(MyOtherEnum.EXAMPLE); // Also fine
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClBANAgjABQBkEoBeKAcmAA8BDCABwBthKAaNAXzTVElhwA8gBcAFsABOSAekw58xUhWr0mrDt14AzMCADGIgJYB7EFDABnYPBkQAFHUkBzAFyC7ASncA3E0YATKBQeNCsbRGR7W2QAOgVCEk8AbigAejSoABUTETpmZjgobSMQYF5wmMh7VQYWNhT0zIA5XKh85hMAd2AA9ihgH1AocRMwZzEoIxFKSxGJKEsGYCgffLByysjq+FEJaTiEpUaMqFaRdoLu3v7B4dHxyenZ+ZWliBW15g32kCC6cz8aAfCAAIykOj0hlM5nCADV1sBHC53LV1A1fP4giEKtYEd8kVUIPE8IkECdMjk8gUiiUymE8YiarQ6hoKVBcMxLCZiqVNoyCdFhOIpHYSYokqlTpzubz6UA)

Even if you create a new enum with the exact same members and name as the initial enum, TypeScript will recognise that they are different and treat them as though they were not interchangeable.

In this case, the enum is also a [const enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums), which means when the TypeScript is compiled that enum's values will be replaced in-place with their actual values, so it will be as though the enum never existed. However, TypeScript still requires that the values be passed by accessing them through the enum.

If you ever need to create an enum-like interface that doesn't have this restriction, you can use an `as const` assertion on a plain JavaScript object to create something that can be used almost identically to an enum. But TypeScript won't create the other parts of an enum for you, such as the type. This is a pattern I use quite a bit in my work:

```js
export const MyEnum = {
  FOO: 'foo',
  BAR: 'bar',
} as const;
export type MyEnum = typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum]; // 'foo' | 'bar'
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLIE8CiyCuAtnALxwDeAUHHAGIDy9AXHAOQBmEErANNXACEAggCUWrAEYBDKL0oBfOFNSIU6ANyVQkWHBhYwwONjxFSeg8AjtjuAoQDaAa2BZrFw+5P2AuurgA9AFsnNxwAD5s0rKUQA)

There are some upsides as well as some downsides to this approach, but in most cases it behaves very similarly to enums created with the `enum` keyword, so it can at least be useful knowing it's an option.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because TypeScript treats the local DocumentOrigin as a different type than the imported one, even though they're the same. To fix it, just import DocumentOrigin in IDocumentFilingDtoGen.ts and make sure that you using enums from this only

Wherever you are using this interface that also requires enum from the same place